# query selector and jqueryfind?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a query selector

```
var thumbnail = file.previewElement.querySelector(".dz-image .image img");
```

and I have written  jquery to find the same elment

```
 var thumbnail2= previewElementForm.find(".dz-image .image img");
```

when I do console.log of both I am getting the same element, but the return type is different it seems.

what is the difference between these 2? can I convert type of thumbnail2 to type of thumbnail1?

Comment: `querySelector` matching first one element only,`find()` matching the multiple elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the difference between these 2?

`.querySelector()` returns a single `DOM` element. `jQuery.fn.find()` can return multiple jQuery objects.

> can I convert type of thumbnail2 to type of thumbnail1?

You can use bracket notation `[index]` or `.get(index)` following `.find()` to get the `DOM` element at the passed index, where `index` is a number from `0` to the number of elements defined in `document` minus `1`.

Comment: why I needed an array?

Comment: can I use javascript to return a nodelist?

Comment: See updated post. `.querySelectorAll()` returns a `NodeList`, not `.querySelector()`, which returns a single element. You can get the first matched element of `.find()` call using `var thumbnail2= previewElementForm.find(".dz-image .image img")[0]` or `var thumbnail2= previewElementForm.find(".dz-image .image img").get(0)`.

Comment: `[index]` and `.get()` return different things. .get(index) returns a `DOM element`while index returns `jQuery Object`.

Comment: @TahaPaksu `var index = 0; var element = jQuery("#element")[index]` returns a `DOM` element, not a jQuery object

Comment: Yep they return the same. I must've been confused it with `.eq()`.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery `.find()` return a set of matched elements.

To have it the same type, you can:

`var thumbnail2 = previewElementForm.find(".dz-image .image img")[0];`

or

`var thumbnail2 = previewElementForm.find(".dz-image .image img").get(0);`